# Wait for WindowState to finish changing

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently working on a snip tool that captures an image of the screen. When I click "New Snip" the program needs to create a screen capture after the tool window has minimized. It currently works like this.

```
//Minimize Tool Window
WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;

//Set delay to allow window to finish its minimizing animation
Thread.Sleep(200);

//Show screen capture with snipping         
SnippingWindow sw = new SnippingWindow();
sw.ShowDialog();

//Close minimized window
Close();
```

Is there a way to wait for the `WindowState` change animation to finish before calling the `SnippingWindow`? I would prefer not to make a `Thread.Sleep` call, but it's the only thing that seems to be working.

I could close the window prior to calling the Snip, but that doesn't seem to "get it out of the way" in time either as it's executed on the same thread.

Comment: Have you tried using the Window.StateChanged event?

Comment: Good idea, but I just tried it and the StateChanged event appears to fire before the state change animation completes. So the snip window is still showing in the screen capture.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out a workaround (although not very clean, but it avoids having to using `Sleep`).

I bound the Window's Opacity to a value that can be changed with a BackgroundWorker. When the BackgroundWorker starts it sets the opacity to 0. Once the worker is complete the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handles the new snip screen shot.

This ensures the tool window is out of the way before the screen shot is taken.

I tried to simply Close the window from the background worker first, but it didn't execute the close operation correctly.

```
private void Bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
       Close();
       SnippingWindow sw = new SnippingWindow();
       sw.ShowDialog();
}

private void Bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     //Windows Opacity is bound to this value.
     //I had to implement iNotifyPropertyChanged on this property. 
     OpacityValue = 0;
}
```